# Getting id of products that belong to category

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have model many-to-many (including pivot table). I need to pull out only the products that belongs to a certain category. I'm trying this but it gives me all the products:

```
 $products = User::whereHas('category', function ($query) {
     $query->where('id','1');
 })->get();
```

`1` in `where` is just for testing because when I put `$id` that was defined outside query it doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Please show the real data sctructure and relations.

Comment: Try this: `$products= User::whereHas('category', function ($query) {
            $query->where('id', '=', '1');
        })->get(); `

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola `where('id', '=', '1')` is the same as `where('id', '1')`

Comment: Show your models and relations.

Comment: Are you trying to get `products` or `users`? Why are you using `Users` model for getting `Products`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$products= User::whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($id) {
            $query->where('id', $id);
        })->get();
```

Comment: This just passes `$id` into closure scope, but doesn't solves OP problem.

Comment: You are trying to access the products in a wrong manner. Can you show the relations between products, category and users ?

Comment: If you want to access the products, there is no way you can do that by querying the User model.  If you want to get the user's products, do

Comment: $user->products

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `fetchProducts` method here will shed some light: [Getting product brands, their categories and associated products](https://github.com/AshMenhennett/Salon-Pricing/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/ProductsController.php)